# Marcar checkbox según base de datos, con tablas relacionadas Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy haciendo una administración, completamente con acciones en AJAX, en algunos puntos se me está complicando.

Tengo tres tablas:

**Tengo una tabla productos**

| id | category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | producto 1 |
| 2 | 4 | producto2 |

**Tabla alérgenos**

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lacteos | lacteos |
| 2 | soja | soja |

**Y una tabla pivote para sacar los alérgenos que tiene cada producto**

| id | product_id | alergeno_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |

Luego mis modelos para hacer las relaciones.

**Modelo product**

```
protected $table = 'products';
protected $primaryKey='id';

public function alergenos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Alergenos::class, 'producto_alergenos', 'product_id', 'alergeno_id');
    }
```

**Modelo Alergenos**

```
    protected $primaryKey='id'; 
    protected $table = 'alergenos';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'producto_alergenos', 'alergeno_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Entonces cuando itero los productos en mi vista:

```
@foreach ($productos as $producto)
    ........
    /*Para iterar los alérgenos que tiene este producto*/
    @foreach ($producto->alergenos as $alerg)

    @endforeach
    ........
@endforeach
```

Pero ahora al editar un producto, lo hago por modales. Entonces itero todos alérgenos en checkbox, de este modo:

```
@foreach ($alergenos as $aler)
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline alergenos">
      <input class="form-check-input ids" type="checkbox" id="alergenos_{{ $aler->id }}" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ $aler->id }}">{{ $aler->name }}</label>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Entonces mi pregunta es, a través de los modelos se puede sacar de alguna manera los checkbox que tiene marcado este producto?? Lo estoy intentando así pero sin éxito:

```
<input class="form-check-input ids" type="checkbox" id="alergenos_{{ $aler->id }}" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}"  @if($aler->id == $producto->products->alergeno_id ) checked @endif>
```

En el controlador no puedo hacer nada, por eso pregunto si se puede hacer con los modelos.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como todas las opciones deben estar disponibles en los checkboxs para cada producto, el loop para crearlos va bien sobre la colección completa de alergenos:

```
/* Iterar todos los alérgenos para imprmir los inputs */
@foreach ($alergenos as $aler)
    <input type="checkbox" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}" />
    <label>{{ $aler->name }}</label>
@endforeach
```

También, en cada iteración condicionalmente agregarle `checked` a cada input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}" @if($condicion) checked @endif>
```

Entonces, la condición para **Marcar el input como `checked`** puede ser:

> Si en los alergenos del producto, existe alguno que tenga la misma `id` que el alergeno de input actual

Y eso, ya que `$producto->alergenos` es una colección, lo puedes hacer usando los [métodos disponibles](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) de las colecciones. Se me ocurre algo así, y seguramente hay más formas de hacerlo:

```
// filtra la colección de alergenos del producto donde la id sea igual al id del alergeno dado
// si la colección resultante no está vacía, devuelve true, si está vacía false
$condicion = $producto->alergenos->where('id', $aler->id)->isNotEmpty();
```

Finalmente esa condición la decides para cada input checkbox

```
@foreach ($alergenos as $aler)
    @php($condicion = $producto->alergenos->where('id', $aler->id)->isNotEmpty())
    <input type="checkbox" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}" @if($condicion) checked @endif />
    <label>{{ $aler->name }}</label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola @porloscerros Ψ gracias por tu respuesta, pero no la logro entender bien. Por ejemplo por que itereas la variable $productos? ya estoy dentro la vista editar productos, no puedo iterarlo, y luego el `@php $condicion ... ` tiene que ir fuera del `foreach` ??

Comment: La condicion es para cada input checkbox, por lo que debe ir dentro del foreach de checkboxs

Comment: Vale ya lo comprendi y funciona perfecto, voy a mirarlo bien para entender el código, gracias como siempre @porloscerros Ψ

Comment: Me funciona perfecto, pero no he tenido la necesidad de poner esto: `Producto: {{ $producto->name }}`

Comment: O sea, eso de crear una variable con el resultado de la condición es opcional, puedes también hacerlo en el if `<input type="checkbox" name="alergenos[]" value="{{ $aler->id }}" @if($producto->alergenos->where('id', $aler->id)->isNotEmpty()) checked @endif />`

Comment: ok ok! lo entiendo. Muchas gracias!! ;)